# ¿Por qué "null instanceof Object" retorna false?

Tags: javascript, object, null

Si `typeof null` es igual a **"object"**, ¿por qué `null instanceof Object` es igual a **false**?

```js
console.log(typeof null);
console.log(null instanceof Object);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es así por diseño, así que la única respuesta objetiva a esta pregunta es ...

> Porque así lo dice la especificación ECMAScript.

En la página de MDN vemos que ellos cumplen con el estandar pero [no están de acuerdo con el mismo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/null#Description):

> ```
> typeof null        // object (bug en ECMAScript, debería ser null)
> typeof undefined   // undefined
> null === undefined // false
> null  == undefined // true
> ```

Si la pregunta es "por qué se diseñó así", el único que podría responder es [Brendan Eich](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich), pero podemos *elucubrar*:

Javascript fue diseñado en tiempo récord y tomó muchas ideas y la sintaxis de Java. En Java sólo una variable cuyo tipo declarado sea una clase puede valer null. Los tipos primitivos no trabajan con null, por lo que en Java tenemos que si declaramos lo siguiente:

```
class A {
    int a;
}
```

Y luego hacemos lo siguiente:

```
A ejemplo = null;
```

Tenemos una variable *cuyo tipo es A* (que extiende Object, como todas las clases), pero puesto que su valor es null *no es todavía una instancia de A*

```
ejemplo instanceof A //devuelve false
```

Una vez que instanciamos:

```
ejemplo= new A();
if (ejemplo instanceof A) {
    println(ejemplo.a;) //0
}
```

La propiedad `a` es de un tipo primitivo que no puede ser null, así que si no declaramos su valor valdrá 0.

Java no tiene el operador typeof porque no lo necesita, sabemos el tipo de las variables porque es un lenguaje con tipado estático.

Volviendo a Javascript, creo que su creador se basó en esto para definir el comportamiento de `typeof` y de `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

Partimos de que `null` es uno de los tipos de datos primitivos que posee **JS** como lenguaje.

- String
- Number
- undefined
- null
- booleanos
- bigint [revisar compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint)

Basándonos en la Especificación de ES<sup>1</sup>, tenemos por ejemplo que para los valores primitivos de tipo `String` estos mismos pertenecen al grupo de los `String` que a su vez **si es una instancia del `Object`**.

Si por ejemplo hacemos esto:

```js
    console.log(String instanceof Object)
```

Lo cual nos devuelve **`true`**

**`String`** posee algunos métodos como los siguientes:

- length
- name
- prototype

Lo mismo pasa ahora con **`Boolean`** que posee métodos como los siguientes:

- apply
- arguments
- bind
- etc.

Sin embargo si ahora nos vamos a la misma especificación, en el apartado: **4.3.11** y **4.3.12** que habla sobre `null value` y `Null Type respectivamente`; donde como notas *no indica pertenecer como miembro de `Object`*

Lo interesante de esto es que podemos leer que es una *ausencia intencional* de valor asignado a una variable o constante....

**EJEMPLO**

En el siguiente script puedes notar por ejemplo que, la variable tiene un valor asignado de: **`null`** y dentro del ciclo de vida del operador ternario comprobamos si efectivamente dicha variable posee ese valor; una vez que eso se confirma le reasignamos un nuevo valor a dicha variable que ahora será un *string*

```js
    let valor = null
    
    console.log((valor === null) ? valor = "Hola" : 0)
```

Si revisas el siguiente enlace<sup>2</sup> podrás encontrar que aunque el hecho de escribir **`typeof null`** devuelva **`object`** esto esta considerado como un *bug* y  no es el valor que realmente debería retornarte.

Por ejemplo si escribes el siguiente código la salida será `0` ya que el valor asignado a la variable no es `null`:

```js
    let valor = 123

    console.log((valor === null) ? 1 : 0)
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [ECMASCRIPT SPEC](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11)
- <sup>2</sup> [Null value](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/null)

Answer (score 0):

Creo la respuesta se debe a que object es el tipo de dato default cuando el tipo de dato no corresponde a ningún otro tipo de dato primitivo de javascript.

Mientras que en la segunda evaluación que haces te devuelve falso porque null por definición no es la instancia de ningúna clase, por tanto da igual contra que lo compares siempre será falso.